# USB audio crackle with SD card access

Tags: usb, audio, sd-card

I am using my pi as an audio server with MPD. I am using an USB sound card (C-Media chip) which works fine quality wise. However, every time the "ACT" LED comes on sound gets distorted with a popping/crackle noise. This is very audible especially in more slow songs and happens every few seconds (depending on what software accesses the SD card I guess).

Is this a known problem? I was unable to find anything for this specific problem on the web. Is this more likely an electrical "interference" of some sort, or a software problem? I am using pulseaudio for output.

Any pointers would be appreciated, as this makes the pi unusable as an audio server.

Comment: Does the USB-card work well in other computers?  Do your power supply supply enough power?

Comment: This seems to be connected to a general USB problem on the original Raspberry PI. See [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23544) for a long disucssion.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that the Pi can give network problems as soon as the CPU must do some extra work. The solution was to use a power-supply that had more power. Perhaps your problem is related to that. A LED (or the process that makes the LED light up) does not consume much but perhaps just enough to have a hiccup in the USB.

Comment: No, it's actually related to well known USB problem, as I found out.

Comment: @ShellfishGene If that were the problem (the pi's USB controller), *everyone* using a USB sound card would likely have it.   However, while there are quite a few questions here from people who are using USB sound cards, [none of them have mentioned this problem previously](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=usb+%22sound+card%22+is%3Aquestion).